# printing white space in strings in C

Tags: c

I have to make a program that prints out my age, name, country by typing an input.
The name has white space, so I have to make it to ignore whitespace and continue to print out.
I successed on the program to not stop on the white space.
But after accepting information and printing out the name, program is stopped. So I can't print out the country part.
Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    float name, country;
    
    printf("Age:");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Name:");
    scanf("%[s^\n]", &name);
    printf("Country:");
    scanf("%s", &country);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: space in a float ?

Comment: I suggest to read a line of input using `fgets` and convert numbers with `strtol`, `strtof`, `strtod` or `sscanf`. Check the return value of all (non-void) functions.

Answer (score 0):

With char arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int age;
    char name[20], country[20];

    printf("Age:");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Name:");
    scanf(" %19[^\n]", name);
    printf("Country:");
    scanf(" %19s", country);

    printf("Your name is %s, you are %d years old and you live in %s.", name, age, country);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code should check the return value of all `scanf` calls.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't want to overload the code too much.

Comment: I think the country needs `scanf(" %19[^\n]", country);` too. My own country is two words.

Answer (score 0):

since you are not reading the `\n` character from the buffer then the `\n` will reside there in the buffer preventing the reading of the `country` variable.

so you should clear the buffer. to that, you can write `fflush(stdin);` but the problem with it is its Undefined behavior in many compilers for different platforms.

the other way to do it is to use the following code:

```
void clearBuffer()
{
    int s = 0;
    while (s != EOF && s != '\n')
    {
        s = getchar();
    }
}
```

where I keep reading all the characters there in the buffer until the buffer is cleared out or I found a valid char in the buffer.

also, there are some problems with your code:

1. it's `char name[50], country[50];` not `float name, country;` as you are trying to read string, not a floating number.
2. it's `scanf("%50[^\n]", name);` not `scanf("%[s^\n]", &name);`

and this is the edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clearBuffer()
{
    int s = 0;
    while (s != EOF && s != '\n')
    {
        s = getchar();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int age;
    char name[50], country[50];

    printf("Age:");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    clearBuffer();

    printf("Name:");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", name);
    clearBuffer();

    printf("Country:");
    scanf("%s", &country);
    clearBuffer();

    printf("your age is : %d\n", age);
    printf("your name is : %s\n", name);
    printf("your country is : %s\n", country);


    return 0;
}
```

and this is some example output:

```
Age:15
Name:natalie samuel
Country:Canada
your age is : 15
your name is : natalie samuel
your country is : Canada
```

Comment: `scanf("%50[^\n]", name);` For a buffer of 50 char, you must put 49 in scanf : `scanf("%49[^\n]", name);`

Comment: If you would add one space to `scanf("%49[^\n]", name);` like this `scanf(" %49[^\n]", name);` then you can remove all the kludgy buffer clearing.

Comment: @CGi03, I agree with you, I didn't notice that,  so I edited the answer

Comment: @WeatherVane, ... but then a name can't start with a space.  Clearing the buffer is not kludgy. It puts the input stream in a known state after each read (at the beginning of the next line) and it is totally necessary if you want to get rid of invalid input in the stream when doing line based input.

Comment: @HAL9000 which names begin with a space? `scanf` has a well defined behaviour for whitespace in the format string and in the input string. If there is *other* bad inout which needs clearing, then `scanf` is the wrong tool for the job. Using a kludge to remove whitespace shows lack of understanding of `scanf` behaviour.

Comment: @WeatherVane, there are a lot of weird names out there.. But it was more a comment on the fact that a generic string input function should not drop whitespace. And it would only work on *correct* input. What if someone typed `5 years\n` when prompted for `age`. Do you then want the string `"years"` to be assigned to `name`?

Comment: @HAL9000 `scanf` is intended for ***f***ormatted input. You need a better way for your "loose" age example, which should cope with `age 5\n` too. And rather than say there are "weird names", *which* name starts with a space?

Comment: @WeatherVane, In an interactive program when someone enter bad input, the program should react. If someone enters `age 5\n` when prompted for `Age`, `scanf` returns `0`, and the line must then *be cleared* from input before being asked again or ignoring the input. If someone enters `5 years\n` then either ` years` must be ignored, or signal bad input. The only way to do that is by reading the rest of the line, including the newline. And since the "Kludge" is needed anyhow, prepending a space in the format string of the next `scanf` serves nothing.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Maybe there is no-one called `" Bob"`, but removing whitespace is not a good generic example on how to input strings

Comment: @HAL9000 an interactive program which needs to deal with bad input should not even be using `scanf`. This is going round in circles. What `scanf` needs to do is to filter whitespace (unless whitespace input is specifically needed by a particular use of `%c` or `%[]`) and check the validity of the supposedly formatted input. If it doesn't match the expected format, then it is ususally a graceful error response (or end of input), not a recovery situation. `scanf` is the **wrong tool** for that.